# Changing iPhone backup location

Tags: iphone, backup

When I try to follow the procedure laid out in [Backup iPhone to external drive on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127562/backup-iphone-to-external-drive-on-mac/154327#154327) and run

```
ln -s /Volumes/DriveName/Backup/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup
```

to change the backup location for my iPad and iPhone terminal tells me that the file directory doesn't exist... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `DriveName` part with the name of your external drive. One way to find the name is to run

```
ls -l /Volumes
```

in Terminal.

Comment: I did that... Seagate Exp is my ext drive name and i replaced DRIVENAME with "Seagate Exp" and get the same result... other thoughts?

Comment: That would be `Seagate\ Exp` in this case (to take care of the space character). If this isn't the issue, can you please add the full error message you get *directly to the question*?

Answer (score 0):

The path you provide must exist. In this case, `/Volumes/DriveName/Backup/` must exist and be writable.